# Coporation LAN(application IP adress to friendly addresses)

Tags: dns, lan, windows-server-2016

I wish to make with my domain dns:

> 150.150.10.5/app1 -> app1(or **if possible** app1.app1)
>
> 150.150.10.5/app2 -> app2(or app2.app2)

app1 and app2 isn't used outsite LAN.

150.150.10.5(static IP) is a ubuntu server 18 with LAMP stack configs.

No need for HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but your question cant be answered as asked and a lot of learning us required to get up to speed.

To correct some misconceptions - the size of your LAN and location of the servers is irrelevant to the process of handling domain to IP mapping.

Also your tags are inconsistent - LAMP implies a Linux OS, Which is somewhat inconsistent with your Windows server tag (are you using Windows for dns?)

Domain resolution works seperately from hosting, so it is not possible to remap a URL (by which I mean name and path) to simply an IP address. The protocols involved. dont allow this.

It is possible to implement a solution by modifying your web server hosting so it hosts each app as a seperate"VirtualHost" or to implement a reverse proxy to do this, but the details of how this us done depend on your webserver setup and also how you handle domain lookups.

If you are doing Apache Hosting learn about VirtualHost directives, mod-proxy and ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse rules.

To comment on your domain resolution we need to know more.aboutnyour setup. You may be able to role out a hosts file, but will more likely need to modify your DNS server environment - which may mean setting up a new ine [or not]. Note that this might require router changes.

Comment: I feel doubtfully in networking, sorry. So i have to make 150.150.10.Y for app2 and 150.150.10.X for app1?-  or did i can do it by ports using apache VirtualHosts? 150.150.10.X:YYYY and 150.150.10.X:XXXX.  And I can't just use windows server DSN PTR like "for this adress: 150.150.10.5/app1 resolve to app1.app1)

Comment: No. You can use a single IP address for both. HTTP (and HTTPS) provide the domain name to the web server as a header, so the server can follow different paths to find the data based on the domain name. Look uo Apache Name Based Virtual Hosting.  The difficulty is you cant include a file path in a URL, so you need to rejig your Apache config to compensate.

Comment: A ptr record does.not help you. You need to use A recorda (theoretically you can usw CNAMEs but dont, they are a minefield). You need to sort out FORWARD DNS, not reverse.DNS. You can put a / in an A, CNAME or PTR record.